# Fourier transform of complex Gamma function

Tags: fourier-analysis, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am wondering if it is known how to evaluate the Fourier transform of the complex Gamma function, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,t\,x}\;\Gamma(1+\mathrm{i}\,t)\;\mathrm{d}t},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
I tried all sorts of substitutions and integral / sum representations for either factor, but it doesn't seem to work easily. Often I seem to encounter a double exponential $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-r}+r}$ in one form or another.

Many thanks.

Comment: The lower limit of the integral should be $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks @MhenniBenghorbal. Given the parity properties of the integrand I'm interested in the integral as it's stated, with limits zero and infinity. Maybe the term Fourier transform is not entirely appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real part of the integral is easily obtained thanks to the Fourier transform (see attachment).
The imaginary part leads to much more difficulties. We even not know if a closed form exists.

[image]

The formula below shows the imaginary part expressed as a Cauchy Principal Value. I doubt that a simpler closed form could be derived.

The numerical tests are in very good agreement with this formula. Sorry, I don't presently publish the analytical calculus leading to the imaginary part because there is still a remaining theoretical difficulty.

[image]

[Typo corrected in the formula : 1/pi was missing ]

Comment: I am very much interested in your answer (in fact for the function $\exp(-s \phi(1+it))$) where $\psi$ is the digamma function. However the images are not charging for me. Could I get them on an external link, or do you prefer I open a new thread with my question?

Comment: @ Desiderius Severus. This is a very old question. Unfortunately I didn't keep the study and draft of my above answer. I suppose that if you open a new thread the subject will be  revived with more answers from someone else.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to my own question. Using the simple power series expansion of the exponential function and recognizing the resulting terms as [A000587](http://oeis.org/A000587) leads to $e^{-x-e^{-x}}$ for the real part of the integral.

Comment: Your formula for the value of the integral leads to the real part, but not to the imaginary part of the integral.

Comment: That's right, I edited my answer.